# Xwiki (Docker Container) Installation cancelled

Tags: docker, xwiki

so I wanted to test Xwiki and the simplest way I thought would be a Docker Container. I never worked with Docker or Wiki before, so my knowledge is very basic. I now have a Xwiki and a mysql container running. But the xwiki installation cancelled when I tried to enter an admin account. How can I return to this installation process without resetting everything?

Thanks.

Comment: resetting everything is probably the fastest solution if you do not know much about docker. 
Do you know enough about docker to open a command line shell in the XWiki container?

Comment: Yes. I think you are right... I will reinstall everything and look what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Could you be more precise when you say "the xwiki installation cancelled when I tried to enter an admin account". Also you should check the xwiki docker documentation at https://hub.docker.com/_/xwiki/ which has explanations on how to use docker's `-v` parameter to map directory in the image to local directories. This allows to rerun or recreate the container without loosing your xwiki data.

Last, you could also ask for help on the xwiki forum site at https://forum.xwiki.org/.

Comment: I already read the Doc, but it did not helped me. Xwiki cancelled during the installation process when I first run it. It was at the moment when it asks for the admin account details. I entered the details and pressed next, and then it stops and directs me to the xwiki page (local xwiki). Now I cannot login or return to the installation steps...

Comment: Sorry, I've tested this tons of time and I've never experienced what you say but it's hard to help you without more information. Maybe you could find the xwiki logs and see if there are errors in it? Regarding "How can I return to this installation process without resetting everything?", I was mentioning that the `-v` parameter allows to rerun the container without loosing anything.

Comment: WDYM by " directs me to the xwiki page (local xwiki)". You mean you have a running XWiki but it's empty? Could it be that you skipped installing the UI at that step: http://platform.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Features/DistributionWizard#HUserInterface ?

Comment: It could be that I skipped it, but without intention. The pictures look different than the installation I saw.. There were 4 steps, and the second step was "Admin Account" where I had to enter name and password for the admin. At this step it stopped suddenly and directs me to the empty main page of my wiki..